# Transferring/inheriting GIS database structure in PostGIS from old project to new one

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, spatial-database, database

I have been given an existing GIS database design for a solar power project, with its structure, relationships, geometry etc designed from another project and existing in PostGIS database. I am supposed to copy and replicate this design, structure, relationships etc and adapt it to suit another solar power project in a different location. The datalayers are similar (point, line, polygon features), aside from the location where the project were carried out which has a different coordinate system. The project is open source using PostGIS and QGIS. I have succeeded in opening and restoring the database in PostGIS via pgAdmin, connecting this to QGIS and I can see the existing layers in QGIS and table in PostGIS.

What would be my next steps in creating a similar type of structure, geometry, relationships for another solar power project instead of creating and designing my own from scratch?

The whole idea is to use an existing database structure that has been tested and minimise time spent starting afresh.

I am familiar with QGIS but quite new using PostGIS with limited coding experience.

Comment: You can dump the database schema without the data.  look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486241/how-can-i-export-the-schema-of-a-database-in-postgresql

Comment: You can dump the schema or database without the data like Encomium said.  You will also need to do alter table statements on all the tables with geometry, in order to set the new srid.  `alter table my_table alter column geom type geometry(point,4326) using st_setsrid(geom,4326)`